# Hide a React component in existing web project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I'm currently trying to integrate a React component into a legacy web project (a huge html index file and some js scripts using mostly jquery).

I am trying to add the rendered react component into a separate tab. Now the problem is that I cannot control the visibility of the top level React component.

Say I have the following src code in html:

```
...
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="react-component"></div>
</div>
...
```

I render the inner component using React. Now is there any way to control the visibility of either "#wrapper" or "#react-component" ? jquery does not help.

I am relatively new to React and it seems that integrating it into old project can be a huge pain.

Comment: `$.hide()` and `$.show()` from jquery don't help ?

Comment: sadly it does not work. $("#react-component").hide() does not work.

Comment: @VittVolt Have you tried using style={{display: 'none'}} for the parent div?

Comment: @Upasana I explicitly set it in the css file, it does not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I render the inner component using React. Now is there any way to control the visibility of either "#wrapper" or "#react-component" ?

Well those are two different worlds.

For the `#wrapper` you can just use DOM manipulation like `$.hide()` and `$.show()` or however you'd normally do it in jQuery.

For the `#react-component` you need to call `ReactDOM.render()`, and you can pass in a `visible` prop to change the visibility of the rendered elements. Something like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent visible={isReactComponentVisible} />, 
  document.getElementById("react-component")
);
```

Now your React component can show or hide itself however you want.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: this.props.visible ? "block" : "none" }}>
        ...
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Of course its up to you to call `ReactDOM.render()` anytime that `isReactComponentVisible` changes. A formal state binding library like [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) could help you here, if the complexity warrants it.

Remember that React will diff the renders so calling `ReactDOM.render()` is *not* rebuilding the entire component's DOM (as jQuery would be), just what changed (ie the DOM effected by the `visible` prop: the `style.display` attribute.)

Answer (score 1):

Create a js file and export a default function to help you rendering react components.

Like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
export default function(component, container , props = {}, callback){      

    React.createElement(component , props);
    ReactDOM.render(component, container, callback);

}
```

Your component will look like this

```
import React,{PropTypes} from 'react';

class MySampleComponent extends React.Component{

   static propTypes ={
      hide : PropTypes.bool
   }
   static defaultProps= {
      hide : false
   }

   render(){
      return(
         <div style={display : this.props.hide : 'none' : 'block'}> </div>

      );



   }

}
```

Import the above function to render your component in js file which you will add in index.html

```
import render from './pathto/RenderHelper'
import MyComponent from './MyComponent' 

class IndexPage {

  constructor(){
     this.renderUI();
  }

  renderUI(){
    var container = document.getElementById('react-component');
    render(MyComponent, container, {hide : false});
  } 
}
```

Note you need to add your page.index.js file to webpack.config.js entry so that webpack can compile it, like this.

```
entry: { page.index : 'location/to/page.index.js' }
```

Hope this helps.